# I need to make a celcius-fahrenheit converter with a tester class and allow the user user to choose whether to go from C to F or F to C

Tags: java

Could someone please explain to me how to make a program with a tester class with this code as its base that will help me do this?
     //This program converts the user input from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa

```
import java.io.*;
class Converter
{
    // variables
    String input;
    double fahrenheit;
    double celcius;

    //constructor with 3 parameters to initialize the variables
    Converter(String converterInput, double converterFahrenheit, double converterCelcius) throws IOException
    {
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(inStream);

        input = converterInput;
        fahrenheit = converterFahrenheit;
        celcius = converterCelcius;

        input = stdin.readLine();
        fahrenheit = Double.parseDouble(input);

        input = stdin.readLine();
        celcius = Double.parseDouble(input);

    }
    // method
    double fahrenheitConverter()
    {
        return fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * celcius + 32;     
    }
    // method2
    double celciusConverter()
    {
        return celcius = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32);
    }
}
```

Comment: help with what exactly?

Comment: what is a "teater class"?

Comment: You are jumping ahead.  This class needs to be cleaned up and improved considerably before it is ready to have a test class written for it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but this was a mess.   :)
Or maybe I didnt had enough time to anticipate the way you wanted to do this.
Anyways I had to change the whole thing.I apologise for this.
Here is a code that works.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
final class Converter
{
    // variables
    double input;
    double fahrenheit;
    double celcius;

    //constructor with 3 parameters to initialize the variables
    Converter() throws IOException
    {
        //InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        String temp;
System.out.print("Please enter the temperature  : ");
Scanner key=new Scanner(System.in);
input = key.nextDouble();
System.out.print("The number you gave is ");
fahrenheit=(fahrenheitConverter(input));
System.out.print(fahrenheit + " fahreneit degree ,  if u entered a celcious value.\n");
celcius=(celciusConverter(input));
System.out.print("Or it is "+ celcius + " celcius degree ,  if u entered a celcious value.\n");


    }
    // method
    double fahrenheitConverter(double inp)
    {
        double iput=inp;
        double fah;
        fah = (iput*1.8)+ 32; 
        return fah;
    }
    // method2
    double celciusConverter(double inp)
    {
        double iput=inp;
        double cel;
        cel=(iput-32)*0.5555;
        return cel;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Converter x=new Converter();
    }
}
```

BUT this is only the code , in the proper (in my view) order.
Program needs to take two information items.Value and metric.
I mean that you have to ask user for the temperature (a double number) and
what is this number , celcius or fahre.
Also you will need some defence , throwing exceptions for ex. like input errors (ex user inputs like , 32,5 , a13 , 2')
Also , I used main() in order to use it compact and take the results easy.
You could have the class and call

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Converter x=new Converter();
    }
```

from outside the class.

I will be happy to give any help beyond this.

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot, I am doing this for a school project and we haven't learned a lot of this stuff but it helps clear up some confusion. The main problem I had however wasn't with the class I had but how clean it and use it in a tester class

Comment: So if it help u can press V in order to help other people in the community with the same problem.Now about the problem , what do u mean by "clean" ??And dont feel sorry for anything , this is a community to help each other , nevertheless I am a student my self.

Comment: how to clean* by clean I mean that everything is where it needs to be, it looks good and runs as planned

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the user specify which way they want to convert. The program doesn't do anything if the user tells the program what the Celsius and Fahrenheit temperatures already are, and you need to create methods to separately convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice versa.

Comment: That is part of what I don't understand how to do. Sorry, I should have added that into the question.